Can a quality gate be setup in PMD? Like a code coverage gate not meeting a certain percentage of code coverage
I want to setup a quality gate that uses the PMD report.  It will not allow the code to be promoted if the code coverage is less than 85% or if the code has 1 critical error or 2 high errors.  I have not been able to find anything on quality gates for PMD.  I found other software that could do the gate part but I was wondering if PMD itself could do this.
Just researching if it is possible with PMD of if I would have to use another product to create the gate.

PMD rules can be assigned priorities and builds can be failed if rule violations above a specific priorities are found.
To configure a specific priority for a rule, see https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_userdocs_configuring_rules.html .
If you create a custom ruleset and put in your most critical rules with priority 1 and other not so important rules with e.g. priority 3.
You can then run PMD on the command line with the option --minimum-priority 1 and only rules with priority 1 are executed. By default, PMD exits with exit code 4 if violations are found, which will break the build.
Then you can run PMD a second time with --no-fail-on-violation to generate a report with all rule violations.
Alternatively you can use two separate rulesets and run PMD twice, like above (with and without --no-fail-on-violation). Then you don't need to configure priorities on each rule. You have one ruleset with important rules that fail the build and another ruleset with not so important rules.
When the build is failed by PMD, then your build pipeline stops and the code is not promoted to the next stage. So, that's the quality gate.
It is however not possible to allow a certain number of violations. Or to differ between violations, that are new or that have been there before. PMD would fail the build, if at least one rule violation has been found.
If you introduce PMD on an existing code base, you need to ramp up the ruleset slowly, adding rule by rule and fixing problems on the way. See also Best practices.
